# How to write media queries in sass?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I was trying to figure out ways to write media queries in sass. This is my code

```css
devices: ("sphone","phone","tablet")
$breakpoints: ( width2: ('sphone' : 320, 'phone' : 360, 'tablet' : 600), height2: ('sphone' : 509, 'phone' : 583, 'tablet' : 952))

=screen-width($device)
  @each $name in $devices
    @if $device != $name
      @error "No device of such name"
  $media: (max-width: map-get(map-get($breakpoints,"width2"),$device) + px )
  @media screen only and ($media)
    @content
  
  
.hello
  background: #333
  @include screen-width("mobile")
    background: #444
```

I am trying to compile the same in sass but it keeps on throwing me the following error. I don't know why.

```
Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code, missing the `$` in `$devices` variable. You write `@include screen-width("mobile")` but mobile isn't in devices list. In `$media` variable `max-width` must be a string and then you have to use interpolation to add in the `@media` rule.

The comparision in the `@each` loop is wrong but I don't solve this for the moment. This code works:

```
$devices: ("sphone","phone","tablet")
$breakpoints: ( width2: ('sphone' : 320, 'phone' : 360, 'tablet' : 600), height2: ('sphone' : 509, 'phone' : 583, 'tablet' : 952))

=screen-width($device)
  $media: "max-width:" map-get(map-get($breakpoints,"width2"),$device) + px
  @media screen only and (#{$media})
    @content

.hello
  background: #333
  @include screen-width("sphone")
    background: #444
```